# Как узнать id гео-объекта?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создаю гео-объект так:

```
var shape = new window.ymaps.GeoObject(features, options);
```

но в данных у него айдишка примерно такого вида:

```
id_323456987654132356: "4488"
```

Как мне узнать значение айдишки?

Думал, что есть что-то подобное:

```
shape.get('id'); // "4488"
```

но нет.

Comment: а зачем вам этот id?

Comment: @Reni я складываю нарисованные на карте фигуры в свой массив из которого потом хочу по айдишке удалять объекты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это внутренняя сущность API.

Задавайте свои `id` в `properties`, как поле в самом объекте или через `WeakMap`.